# The set $\{ n\in \mathbb{N}: T_{n}>t \}$ is not empty almost surely

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $ S_ {1}, S_ {2}, ... $ exponential iid variables of parameter $ \lambda $. We define $ T_{0} = 0 $ and $ T_{n} = S_{1} + ... + S_{n} $. I must prove that for all $ t \geq 0 $, it is true that $ \{n\in \mathbb{N}: T_{n}> t \} \neq \varnothing $ almost surely.

Actually this result seems very obvious to me but they ask me for a rigorous proof. I made the following solution and I would like to know if it is correctly formulated and rigorous enough:

Let $A = \{ \omega\in \Omega:  \{ n: T_{n}(\omega)>t \}=\varnothing  \}$. I must show that $P(A)=0$. As $ T_ {n} \sim \text{Gamma}(n,\lambda)$, then: $$P(T_{n}\leq x)=1-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(\lambda x)^{k}e^{-\lambda x}}{k!}$$

Now let's take $ \omega \in A $. This means that  $T_{n} (\omega) \leq t $ for all $ n \in \mathbb{N} $, then $\omega \in T_{n}^{-1}((-\infty,t])$. Therefore $A\subset T_{n}^{-1}((-\infty,t])$ for all $n$. Hence: $$P(A)\leq \lim_{n} P(T_{n}\leq t)=\lim_{n} \left( 1-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(\lambda x)^{k}e^{-\lambda x}}{k!}\right)=1-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\lambda x)^{k}e^{-\lambda x}}{k!}=0$$

and therefore it is true that $ P (A) = 0 $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to show that $A$ is measurable. Write $A$ as $\bigcap_n\{\omega: T_n(\omega) \leq t\}$. Since each $T_n$ is measurable it follows that $A$ is measurable. Rest of your argument is fine.